# Как посчитать количество обьектов в суб-суб таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть вот такая структура

```
CREATE TABLE `rooms` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `name` (`name`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=3
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `students` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_room_id` INT(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `student_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_students_room` (`ref_room_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_students_room` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_room_id`) REFERENCES `university`.`rooms` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `possessions` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ref_student_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK__students` (`ref_student_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK__students` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_student_id`) REFERENCES `university`.`students` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

Теперь добавляю сюда данные

```
INSERT INTO `university`.`rooms` (`name`) VALUES ('a');
INSERT INTO `university`.`rooms` (`name`) VALUES ('b');

INSERT INTO `university`.`students` (`ref_room_id`, `student_name`) VALUES ('3', '1');
INSERT INTO `university`.`students` (`ref_room_id`, `student_name`) VALUES ('3', '2');
INSERT INTO `university`.`students` (`ref_room_id`, `student_name`) VALUES ('3', '3');
INSERT INTO `university`.`students` (`ref_room_id`, `student_name`) VALUES ('3', '4');

INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('7', 'a');
INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('7', 'aa');
INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('7', 'aaa');
INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('8', 'aaaa');
INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('9', 'aaaaa');
INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('6', 'aaaaaa');
INSERT INTO `university`.`possessions` (`ref_student_id`, `name`) VALUES ('7', 'aaaaaaa');
```

Мне нужно получить таблицу в которой будет показано классы потом сколько студентов (количество) в каждом классе и сколько вещей у всех студентов в этом классе (пример внизу)

[image]

для этого я создал procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_data`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN

SELECT r.id AS room_id, r.name, COUNT(s.id) AS student_num, COUNT(p.id) AS possessions_num
FROM rooms r 
INNER JOIN students s ON s.ref_room_id = r.id
INNER JOIN possessions p ON p.ref_student_id = s.id
GROUP BY r.name;

END
```

Но результат получается вот такой

[image]

Что делаю не так?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b606c9c3e2eb4baaaa879da6a819b38

Comment: @Akina я понял в чем была ошибка, спасибо это помогло, я вот только не пойму почему влияет DISTINCT на результат? если я делаю джоин только из одной таблицы то это работает нормально, но если я делаю джоин и для второй таблицы то без DISTINCT это не работает... но DISTINCT у него другая задача и я не пойму как он в этом query делает так что это работает правильно?

Comment: *почему влияет DISTINCT на результат?* С ним COUNT() считает не количество записей вообще, а только количество уникальных значений. Если есть 3 записи с пятёркой, без DISTINCT получишь три, а с ним - один.